# Why is the bias neuron in neural network always initialised to 1?

Tags: neural-networks, bias

I'm just starting with neural networks wherein this [towards data science](https://towardsdatascience.com/why-we-need-bias-in-neural-networks-db8f7e07cb98) article mentions that bias neuron is always initialized to 1. My question is why is the bias neuron in Neural networks is always initialized to 1 ? Can we initialize it to other positive and negative values say 2 or 3 or maybe 100 or -200 ? How will the output and training of the neural network get affected if we initialize with other values apart from 1

Comment: yes you can initialise it to anything.  However, particular weight initialisation implementations might assume it being one.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, we can. there are many ways to initialize the weights for neural network.

In fact, I do not agree with "bias neuron is always initialized to 1".

Search `neural network weight initialization` in google scholar to get more information.

Comment: I think he just means the hypothetical "neuron" that stands in for a source, as in $y = W \cdot x + 1 \cdot b$